# Accessing 'this' (component instance) from a template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

Suppose we need to bind some child component property to a component instance itself in a template:

```
<child-component parent="???"></child-component1>
```

Is there a way to do it except declaring a dedicated property on the parent component:

```
public thisInstance: ParentComponent = this;
```

and then using it:

```
<child-component parent="thisInstance"></child-component1>
```

?

**UPDATE 1**: I'm looking for a way which allows to definitely provide a parent to a child meaning that if the child has two or more parents of the same component type on different levels of hierarchy, we would be able to definitely specify which one has to be used.

**UPDATE 2**: I'm looking for an approach without limiting the child what exact type of the parent could be used. So, I'm not sure if injecting a parent into child's constructor using some base class (which is implemented by the parent) as token would work.

Comment: That's generally not good practice anyway. You should be communicating between the parent and the child using template bindings, not passing the entire object in.

Comment: `[parent]="this"` should work

Comment: @yurzui: That works, thank you! Could you post an answer so I'm able to accept it? I created a demo [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/component-bind-to-this).

Answer (score 0):

You can try binding HTML with #selector, for example:

```
<child-component1 #parent [parent]="parent"></child-component1>
```

And then you can declare a parent as @Input() in child-component1.

Comment: How would you use this technique to pass the parent component to the child? In your example, you pass the child to itself (which is not very useful).

Answer (score 0):

You can inject parent component inside child component constructor like this

```
export class childComponent{
  constructor(private parent: ParentComponent){}
}
```

To accomodate both updates, you can create a service injectable class and assign the parent component instance in parent component oninit(), the same instance will be used in child component.

```
@Injectable()
export class Service{
  private compInstance;
  setComponentInstance(_instance){
    this.compInstance = _instance;
  }
  getComponentInstance(_instance){
    this.compInstance = _instance;
  }
}
```

**Parent Component**

```
export class Parent{
    this.service.setComponentInstance(this);
}
```

**Child Component:**

```
this.service.getComponentInstance();
```

Comment: Thank you and excuse me for not mentioning some details in the first place! Could you check both updates in my question to see if your approach would satisfy those requirements, please?

Comment: This approach won't fit this use case. Updated above.